# Cipher Options In Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, encryption

I see 2 ways to use a cipher and TLS1_2 for tomcat.

Add it to the java startup options

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

or

Edit server.xml, in the Connector block

```
<Connector sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
....>
```

My question is, are both required?  Does one trump the other?  Which one is preferred?

If you choose server.xml, does SSLEnabled="false" have to be set to "True".